# With Thymeleaf how do I display an iteration through an arraylist?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, arraylist, thymeleaf

In my controller I have a loop that iterates through an arraylist and displays the attributes belonging to each object in the arraylist and I am wondering what should I put in my thymeleaf code because at the moment it is only displaying the information of the first object in the arraylist.

My Controller class

```
   @GetMapping("/allSubjects")
public String shoSubjects(@ModelAttribute("subject") @Valid UserRegistrationDto userDto, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    Authentication loggedInUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String email = loggedInUser.getName();   

    User user = userRepository.findByEmailAddress(email);

    ArrayList<String> subjects = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(Subject sub:user.getSubject())
    {
        subjects.add(sub.getSubjectName());
    }
    model.addAttribute("subjects", subjects);


    if(!subjects.isEmpty()) {

    for(int i = 0; i<subjects.size(); i++) {

            String subjectName = (subjects.get(i));
            Subject subject = subjectRepository.findBySubjectName(subjectName);

            String subjectName1 = subject.getSubjectName();
            Double subjectGradeGoal = subject.getSubjectGradeGoal();
            Double caCompletedWorth = subject.getCaCompletedWorth();
            Double subjectResults = subject.getSubjectResults();
            Double maxSubRemMarks = subject.getMaxSubRemMarks();
            Double marksNeededToReachGoal = subject.getMarksNeededToReachGoal();
            Boolean isGoalPossible = subject.getIsGoalPossible();
            Double highestPossibleGrade = subject.getHighestPossibleGrade();

            model.addAttribute("subjectName",subjectName1);
            model.addAttribute("subjectGradeGoal",subjectGradeGoal);
            model.addAttribute("caCompletedWorth",caCompletedWorth);
            model.addAttribute("subjectResults",subjectResults);
            model.addAttribute("maxSubRemMarks",maxSubRemMarks);
            model.addAttribute("marksNeededToReachGoal",marksNeededToReachGoal);
            model.addAttribute("isGoalPossible",isGoalPossible);
            model.addAttribute("highestPossibleGrade",highestPossibleGrade);
            return "allSubjects";

        }


    }

return "allSubjects";

}
```

My html class

```
  <>Subject: <h4 th:text="${subjectName}" /> </>
```

//I have this for each attribute I have just not added it in for this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your function `user.getSubject()` returns a collection or an array of Subject objects, do something like the below

Controller Method

```
@GetMapping("/allSubjects")
public String shoSubjects(@ModelAttribute("subject") @Valid UserRegistrationDto userDto, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    Authentication loggedInUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String email = loggedInUser.getName();   
    User user = userRepository.findByEmailAddress(email);

    model.addAttribute("subjects", user.getSubject());
    return "allSubjects";
}
```

And in the view

```
<div th:each="subject : ${subjects}">
    Subject: <h4 th:text="${subject.subjectName}" />
    Subject Grade Goal: <h4 th:text="${subject.subjectGradeGoal}" />
    <!-- Other Properties -->
</div>
```

P.S. It is bad to name your method as `user.getSubject()` when it returns multiple subjects. It would be better if you modify your method name to `user.getSubjects()` which implies by its name that multiple objects are returned.

Answer (score 1):

There is no sense in passing every attribute separately. You can just add the Subject to the model, and use thymeleaf to display each Subject's attribute. If you pass the `ArrayList<Subject>` to the thymeleaf, you can also iterate through the list with for each and display only the attributes you like.

You can then use thymeleaf to create a list, table, whatever you want, to iterate through the objects. Example:

```
<ul th:each="subject : ${subjects}">
    <li th:text="${subject.subjectName}"/>
    <li th:text="${subject.subjectName}"/>
<ul/>
```

Comment: Thanks for that I will try that instead, but in reference to my question how do I iterate through the list with thymeleaf?